# tomcat wont start on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, vps

**[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728147/tomcat-wont-start-on-ubuntu-server)**

**Updated on 31/05/2012**

I have a VPS and running a Tomcat server over a year without a problem. However, Tomcat just shutdowns right after VPS maintain and can not start again a week ago. So I look into catalina.out and found that my VPS missing a Apache Tomcat Native library:

```
root@cdou:/home/tomcat/logs# vim catalina.out May 28, 2012 8:32:02 AM
org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: The APR based
Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
```

so I googled around and install libtcnative-1, but still no luck, now catalina.out give me this:

```
An older version 1.1.19 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends a minimum version of 1.1.2
```

Comment: Your JRE is likely out of date as opposed to missing a lib.

Comment: That part of the log doesn't seem to show the real issue, is that all?

Answer (score 1):

I would :

1. Look for any specific listeners that the applications configured use
2. Temporary disable iptables so I can be sure that the ports aren't blocked
3. Look if the is any specific binding to an IP .
4. Launch Tomcat manually (not as a service ) and look at what errors it trows at start up .

I hope this helps .

Comment: i tried to disable iptables but still not working, the problem is probably related to Apache Tomcat Native library.

Answer (score 0):

The native library installation is an optimisation and won't stop tomcat starting.

Hence the alert message is only logged at the `INFO` level;

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance 
in production environments was not found
```

Hence you would be looking for some other message at the `SEVERE` or `CRITICAL` level:

You can search for serious startup errors like so;

```
# egrep "(SEVERE|WARN|CRIT|ERROR)" /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out

SEVERE: The web application [/republish] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-1608] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
SEVERE: The web application [/republish] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-1609] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

To double check the status you can run `netstat -lntp | grep :8080` to check whether its listening;

```
# netstat -lntp | grep ":8080"
tcp        0      0 :::8080      :::*        LISTEN     32195/java
```

also look for it in the process list;

```
# ps -ef | grep tomcat
root     20558 20374  0 13:39 pts/0    00:00:00 grep tomcat
tomcat   32195     1  1 May27 ?        00:56:16 /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -classpath :/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat6/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

if you have port 8080 listening, and you have the entry in the `ps -ef` output, then its gone through through the startup phase, and is running a server on port 8080.

If you still have nothing, then please post the rest of the catalina.out file that was logged during tomcat6 start phase.